# Question about Stub Network?

Tags: routing, router

Rephrasing: I want to know if Router A need to be set by a network administrator of Stub Network...

I meant about the IP configuration.. Router A belongs a stub network? In this case the IP configuration for Router A, Who do? Administrator of Stub Network or ISP ( If Router A not belongs a Stub)

[image: Stub Network]

Comment: Hi. You're being downvoted because your question isn't clear. You may want to consider trying to rephrase it.

Comment: now? it's better?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's not clear what you mean by 'router needs to be set'.

Comment: sorry about that, I meant about the IP configuration..  Router A belongs a stub network? In this case the IP configuration for Router A, Who do? Administrator of Stub Network or ISP ( If Router A not belongs a Stub)

Comment: "Stub Network" is a network accessed by a single router! On the left-hand side of the diagram are others networks! Static routing is used often in kind of network! The router A is being configured with a Static IP for access the Stub network.. Assuming that my company is that stub network and I'm network administrator, Who will configure the IP in Router A? Me or a ISP?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

> Who will configure the IP in Router A? Me or a ISP?

There is a very basic notion here.  The person that owns a thing has responsibility for its configuration.

- If you own Router A, then you configure it.
- If your ISP owns Router A, then the ISP configures it.

I can't imagine a IT world which operates otherwise and actually works reliably.

> "Stub Network" is a network accessed by a single router!

Incidentally, the network behind Router B is not commonly called a "stub network" in English.  It's just called "my company's network" or "the network behind Router B".

When you say "stub", that carries a loaded meaning to network professionals, particularly since OSPF has [stub networks](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/how-ospf-decides-a-network-to-be-a-stub-network); so does [EIGRP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_0s/feature/guide/eigrpstb.html)